# Overstay penalties in Philippines

Tags: overstaying, philippines, french-citizens

I'm a French citizen, I'm already in Philippines for 36 months. Normally I have to leave on September 17, 2018, means today. For personal reasons I'll be probably late, then I have to do my ECC.

How much total fees and fines will I be expected to pay when I depart after my overstay? Are there any other penalties that I can expect?

Comment: Did you paid? How many days they give your passport

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.